# Generating a natural number ouf of PHP's lcg_value()?

Tags: php, math, numbers

I want to produce a natural number (a positive integer between 0 and x) by using [lcg_value()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php). This is what I can see from the actual source code for the function:

```
/*
 * combinedLCG() returns a pseudo random number in the range of (0, 1).
 * The function combines two CGs with periods of
 * 2^31 - 85 and 2^31 - 249. The period of this function
 * is equal to the product of both primes.
 */
```

Now, how would I turn that float into a natural number so that I do not lose information/entropy. Currently I just do it like this:

```
$number = pow(2,31) * lcg_value();
```

However, I have a feeling in my gut that it's not perfect. How about 2^62? Or perhaps 2^31-334? Or 2^62-334? I don't know.

Comment: How does 334 apply to this situation?

Comment: Probably no way, it's just a sum of 85 and 249.

Comment: The doc you posted for that function is basically saying that the sequence of random numbers is (2^31 - 85) * (2^31 - 249) long. In other words, once you've called it that many times in a row, you'll start getting the orignial sequence again. It doesn't say anything about precision, though, which what you are concerned about.

Comment: You could retain the entropy *if* you could get access to the LCG int state variables. I suspect that lcg_value() does division under the hood, and not by a power of 2, so that the resulting rational numbers are not representable exactly as floating point. In other words, you are going to lose information no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either type float or int are bounded by platform

> > **Integer** The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.
> >
> > **float** The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

to maintain highest precision of float, u can refer http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php